# How can I find the source code of Error Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When I try to inspect the source code of the Error Object in Chrome's console, it showed this:

```
function Error() { [native code] }
```

---

Why I need the source code?
1) In this way,i could get the ErrorStackTrace

```
Error().stack // output: ErrorStackTrace
```

2) Another way

```
var obj = {};
Error.call(obj);
obj.stack; // output: undefined
Error.captureStackTrace(obj);
obj.stack; // output: ErrorStackTrace
```

I want to known what happened in function Error() that make stack not assign to `this` pointer.

Comment: You can find it in the Chrome source code. However, you don't need that to see the stack. Just evaluate `new Error().stack`.

Comment: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main:v8/src/api/api.cc;drc=e0e0d24aaa54727dc0a8bc4b159ccdf80d3f5d8d;l=10485

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here: [MDN: Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Comment: But I want to find the source code of Error Object, not how to use the Error Object.

Comment: The Error object will probably be implemented in a language other than JavaScript, C++ I assume. Therefore, it is compiled and the source code is no longer available. Why do you need the source?

Comment: Sorry,my fault. I have appended the reason of  why I need the source just now.